# Python - How to delete/hide brackets and "array(value)" when printing an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm multiplying a matrix (15,15) with an array (15,1) to just print the values of 6 positions of the new array. However, when I print these new array, python prints the value like these: `[[array([20238.49170303])]]`. How can I delete all of the brackets and the "array"?

Here is my code:

```
r = np.dot(kportico, utotal) - f

rp = np.array([[r[0]],
               [r[1]],
               [r[2]],
               [r[12]],
               [r[13]],
               [r[14]]])

rv = np.array([["R1x ="],
               ["R1y ="],
               ["M1 ="],
               ["R5x ="],
               ["R5y ="],
               ["M5 ="]])


uni = np.array([["N"],
                ["N"],
                ["N*m"],
                ["N"],
                ["N"],
                ["N*m"]])

size = len(rv)

print(" ")
print(" ")

if len(rv) == len(rp) and len(rv) == len(uni):
    for x in range(size):
        print(rv[x],rp[x],uni[x])
```

The print that returns is:

```
['R1x ='] [[array([20238.49170303])]] ['N']
['R1y ='] [[array([77650.64938379])]] ['N']
['M1 ='] [[array([6.69388101e-09])]] ['N*m']
['R5x ='] [[array([-50238.49170304])]] ['N']
['R5y ='] [[array([86650.64938382])]] ['N']
['M5 ='] [[array([4.07453626e-10])]] ['N*m']
```

And I would like to make the print much more cleaner:

```
R1x = 20238.49170303 N
R1y = 77650.64938379 N
M1 = 6.69388101e-09 N*m
R5x = -50238.49170304 N
R5y = 86650.64938382 N
M5 = 4.07453626e-10 N*m
```

Comment: Do a bit of research into string formatting with f-strings.

Comment: I took your advice, but I'm not sure how f-string will help me here.

Comment: **Caveat:** Not thoroughly tested. Perhaps something along the lines of the following, to compensate for the array nesting: `f'{rv[x][0]} {rp[x][0][0][0]} {uni[x][0]}'`. (Might need some modification to meet your specific requirements.)

Comment: Why all the extra brackets in those arrays?  It makes the shapes (6,1).  `rv[x]` is a (1,) shape array.  `rv[x,0]` is a string.  Brackets aren't just decoration, on input or display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created (n,1) shaped arrays

```
In [283]: x = np.array([[1],[2],[3]]); y = np.array([['one'],['two'],['three']])

In [284]: x
Out[284]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])

In [285]: y
Out[285]: 
array([['one'],
       ['two'],
       ['three']], dtype='<U5')

In [286]: x.shape
Out[286]: (3, 1)
```

If you iterate on the first dimension, the elements are `(1,)` shaped arrays, and display as such:

```
In [287]: for i in range(3):
     ...:     print(y[1],x[i])
     ...:     
['two'] [1]
['two'] [2]
['two'] [3]
```

If the arrays are 1d, flattened (if needed):

```
In [288]: x1 = x.ravel(); y1 = y.ravel()

In [289]: x1.shape
Out[289]: (3,) 
In [291]: x1,y1
Out[291]: (array([1, 2, 3]), array(['one', 'two', 'three'], dtype='<U5'))
```

Now `y1[0]` is a string, and `x1[0]` is a number:

```
In [292]: for i in range(3):
     ...:     print(y1[1],x1[i])
     ...:     
two 1
two 2
two 3
```

And adding a bit of formatting to the print:

```
In [294]: for i in range(3):
     ...:     print(f'{y1[1]} = {x1[i]}')
     ...:     
two = 1
two = 2
two = 3
```

You could also use 2d indexing on the 2d arrays:

```
In [297]: for i in range(3):
     ...:     print(f'{y[1,0]} = {x[i,0]}')
     ...:     
two = 1
two = 2
two = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a set of characters which have to be removed from the string and then use the *.join()* function in this way:

```
    stringa = ''.join([c for c in stringa if c not in chars])
```

where:

- `stringa = "{}{}{}".format(rv[x], rp[x], uni[x])`
- `chars = ['[',']',"'"]`

Here the *.join()* function just takes the characters inside *stringa* that are not present in the set of what we could call "the forbidden characters", or better, the characters we want to remove.

As for testing it i wrote down the following code starting from what you provided:

```
# characters to remove
chars = ['[',']',"'"]

if len(rv) == len(rp) and len(rv) == len(uni):
    for x in range(size):
        stringa = "{}{}{}".format(rv[x], rp[x], uni[x])
        stringa = ''.join([c for c in stringa if c not in chars])
        print(stringa)
```

Comment: It’s unnecessary to build the extra list inside the `join` function, which can take the iterator itself.  For example: `''.join(i for i in 'string')`.